# Flowchart library for react application

Tags: reactjs, pixi.js, flowchart, cytoscape, react-flow

I am trying to create data visualization UI ( flowchart with nodes and edges ) on a react application that looks like the screenshot below. I am currently using [Reactflow](https://reactflow.dev/) library  . But due to the limitation in the number of nodes (limit is 100 nodes) that we can render, I am migrating to another library which can support up to 1000~5000 nodes. I was wondering if there is any flowchart libraries that we can use!

Here are the requirements

- Render at least 1000 nodes. (5000 would be more than safe for now)
- Good Layout(such as hierarchical layout using dagre or elkjs) the nodes and edges ( better if it provides fine tuning through parameters and variety of layouts)
- User interactions available(pan, zoom, node selection, node editing etc)
- Group nodes into parent and children relationship and collapse/expand the children of a parent

[Data visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOf32.png)

Comment: This will likely be closed, because it is asking for a recommendation. Still, if the number of nodes is important to you, here is a library with the best layouts available that can render several millions of nodes if your GPU isn't from the last century :-) https://www.yworks.com/pages/react-graph-component

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. This library seems to be quite expensive from our perspective. But thanks of the suggestion. I had no idea such a performative library with diverse functionalities existed. It's definitely good to know.

Comment: Hey, @JiunKim I am planning to use ReactFlow library but I am not seeing any limitation on the node number in their documentation. Is it something stated somewhere or is it your experience? (I mean the limit of 100 nodes)